# Weird minecraft-like terrain generation

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to implement minecraft-like game using opengl.
So i've got to the point where i want to replace stupid mesh generation with culling.

View of a terrain with no between-chunks culling: [image: img]

View inside a terrain: [image: img]

It worked fine but when i try to also cull those blocks between chunks, things go weird.

View of a terrain when added between-chunks culling: [image: img]

Here is the code of mesh generating:

```
void Chunk::CreateMesh()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < CHUNK_SIZE; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < CHUNK_SIZE; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < CHUNK_SIZE; z++)
            {
                BlockType currentBlock = blocks[x][y][z];
                BlockChunkPosition currentPos(x, y, z);
                if (currentBlock != BlockType::AIR)
                {

                    // Right face
                    if (GetBlock(x + 1, y, z) == BlockType::AIR || GetBlock(x + 1, y, z) == BlockType::LEAVES)
                    {
                        mesh.AddFace(RIGHT_FACE, currentBlock, currentPos);
                    }

                    // Left face
                    if (GetBlock(x - 1, y, z) == BlockType::AIR || GetBlock(x - 1, y, z) == BlockType::LEAVES)
                    {
                        mesh.AddFace(LEFT_FACE, currentBlock, currentPos);
                    }

                    // Top face
                    if (GetBlock(x, y + 1, z) == BlockType::AIR || GetBlock(x, y + 1, z) == BlockType::LEAVES)
                    {
                        mesh.AddFace(TOP_FACE, currentBlock, currentPos);
                    }

                    // Bottom face
                    if (GetBlock(x, y - 1, z) == BlockType::AIR || GetBlock(x, y - 1, z) == BlockType::LEAVES)
                    {
                        mesh.AddFace(BOTTOM_FACE, currentBlock, currentPos);
                    }

                    // Front face
                    if (GetBlock(x, y, z + 1) == BlockType::AIR || GetBlock(x, y, z + 1) == BlockType::LEAVES)
                    {
                        mesh.AddFace(FRONT_FACE, currentBlock, currentPos);
                    }

                    // Back face
                    if (GetBlock(x, y, z - 1) == BlockType::AIR || GetBlock(x, y, z - 1) == BlockType::LEAVES)
                    {
                        mesh.AddFace(BACK_FACE, currentBlock, currentPos);
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
BlockType Chunk::GetBlock(int x, int y, int z)
{
    try
    {
        return blocks.at(x).at(y).at(z);
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range &)
    {
        BlockWorldPosition pos = ToWorldCoordinates(position, BlockChunkPosition(x, y, z));
        return terrain->GetBlock(pos);
    }
}

BlockType Terrain::GetBlock(BlockWorldPosition pos)
{
    ChunkPosition chunkPos;
    chunkPos = GetChunkPos(pos);

    BlockChunkPosition blockPos;
    blockPos = GetBlockLocalPos(pos);


    ChunkTable::iterator currentChunk;
    if(((currentChunk = chunks.find(chunkPos)) != chunks.end()))
    {
        return currentChunk->second->GetBlock(blockPos.x, blockPos.y, blockPos.z);
    }
    return BlockType::AIR;
}
```

When I use the debugger, it works strangely in try-catch block. Is there anything wrong there?

What can cause such problem?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JesperJuhl sorry, updated

Comment: That `catch` is really a bad idea. Just crash, burn, drop and roll in case someone accesses out of bounds. [And instead of taking three ints, be explicit!](https://github.com/bananu7/MiniCraft/blob/master/src/Minefield.h#L104-L106) (feel free to steal more ideas from that repo, there's the block culling there as well).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I replaced the try-catch block with if statement and it still works the same :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. This issue occured because I bound vertex and index buffer a few extra times when it wasn't needed. The vetrex array alredy had the buffers bound to it.

```
void ChunkMesh::GenerateMesh()
{
    ibo.Bind();
    vbo.Bind();
    vao.Bind();
    vbo.GenerateBuffer(sizeof(float) * mesh.size(), &mesh[0]);
    ibo.GenerateBuffer(indices.size(), &indices[0]);
    vao.AddBuffer(vbo, layout);
}
```

replaced with

```
void ChunkMesh::GenerateMesh()
{
    vao.Bind();
    vbo.GenerateBuffer(sizeof(float) * mesh.size(), &mesh[0]);
    ibo.GenerateBuffer(indices.size(), &indices[0]);
    vao.AddBuffer(vbo, layout);
}
```

And

```
void ChunkMesh::Render()const
{
    ibo.Bind();
    vao.Bind();
    shader.Bind();
    GLCall(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0));
}
```

I replaced with

```
void ChunkMesh::Render()const
{
    vao.Bind();
    shader.Bind();
    GLCall(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0));
}
```

Although, I still don`t completely understand why this happened.